# Laravel installation with wordpress blog out of the public folder

Tags: wordpress, laravel, .htaccess

I have a Laravel installation and a Wordpress instalation in diferent folders but in the same server

laravel.site.com (domain and folder with all laravel files)

wordpress.site.com (domain and folder with all wp files)

but I need to make the wordpress blog can be accessed in this url laravel.site.com/blog

I have tried adding this to the laravel public htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/
```

and I changed the wordpress WP_SITEURL but it does not work it show 404

I also checked the laravel routes and it only have

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

I have tried many similar questions without result, any idea of how to fix this?

Comment: Try putting wordpress files inside "public" folder of laravel installation.

Comment: I'm doing it, but I get a 404 if I go to /blog I've edited the htaccess in both without results :\

Answer (score 1):

Put wordpress files within "public" folder in a folder say "blog". Change the .htaccess file of Wordpress to below

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Your site url within wordpress should be "http://laravel.site.com/blog"